# Google Maps Zoom and Description dialog not working right

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Well I'm having a couple problems getting google maps to work using the v3 API.

Look here: [Removed by Poster]

Both maps are, in fact, working but the zoom level seems like it is random. The zoom is set to 12 when the map is initialized. Also, if you click on the marker, the description box is missing corners and is unable to be closed. Here is the javascript functions I am using to activate these maps:

```
var mapHash = [];
var bound = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
finishedCoding = false;
function initMap(map_container_div,lat,lng) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom:12,
        center:latlng,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        streetViewControl: false
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(map_container_div), myOptions);
    if (!getMap(map_container_div)) {
        var mapInfo = {
            mapkey:'',
            map:'',
            geocoder : new google.maps.Geocoder()
        };
        mapInfo.map = map;
        mapInfo.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        mapInfo.mapKey = map_container_div;
        mapHash.push(mapInfo);
    }
}

function placeMarker(myAddress, mapId, description, title) {
    mapIndex = getMap(mapId)
    //alert(myAddress + mapId + map)
    mapHash[mapIndex].geocoder.geocode({
        'address':myAddress
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            mapIndex = getMap(mapId)
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map:mapHash[mapIndex].map,
                position:results[0].geometry.location,
                title: title
            });
            bound.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
            mapHash[mapIndex].map.fitBounds(bound);

            finishedCoding = true;
            placeDesc(marker,description,mapId);

        }
    });
}

function placeDesc(marker,myDesc,mapId) {
    mapIndex = getMap(mapId);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: myDesc
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(mapHash[mapIndex],marker);
    });
}

function getMap(mapKey) {
    for (var i = 0 ; i < mapHash.length ; i++) {
        if (mapHash[i].mapKey == mapKey) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function startmap(mapidd,address,description,title,lat,lng) {
    initMap(mapidd,lat,lng)
    placeMarker(address,mapidd,description,title)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue myself and am kicking myself for not thinking of this. :)

Just had to add `mapHash[mapIndex].map.setZoom(12);`

And I removed the following 2 codes:

```
bound.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
mapHash[mapIndex].map.fitBounds(bound);
```

Answer (score 2):

by just removeing

```
body img {
max-width: 520px !important;
height: auto !important;}
```

from style sheet

http://www.wppassport.com/wp-content/plugins/easyfanpagedesign/default.theme/style.css

your problem is resolved now

Comment: This actually makes no difference. =/

Comment: Actually i just sent u solution for 
"the description box is missing corners and is unable to be closed."

and for get to put setZoom option. if u again place that style sheet then u observe the same issue with the description box.

Comment: Ah you are right, that does fix the corners issue, but for some reason the dialog boxes still won't close when the x is clicked. That's not so much of a big deal compared to the setZoom function I needed. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

Your dialog boxes aren't closing because of a javascript error.
Something is wrong with `infowindow.open(mapHash[mapIndex],marker);` inside your click listener. It's displaying the window, which makes you think that the error is happening after, but I'm pretty sure it's in the call itself. When I debugged you weren't making an obvious mistake, but I still think that that line of code is the culprit.